# regex, find 10 characters before pattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm not good at regex so I need some help.

I'm trying to find how to get for example 10 characters before the pattern and 10 characters after.
like:

```
dskjgh kdsfhgl:ks;dhfl\kgh.sldfgdfgsd<pattern1.fso[wpe;x,/c,zasdfsdg


(10 chars before pattern1) var1 = "ldfgdfgsd<"
(10 chars after pattern1)  var2 = ".fso[wpe;x"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = "dskjgh kdsfhgl:ks;dhfl\\kgh.sldfgdfgsd<pattern1.fso[wpe;x,/c,zasdfsd";
preg_match( "/(.{10})(pattern1)(.{10})/", $str, $matches);

$var1 = $matches[1];
echo $var1;

$var2 = $matches[3];
echo $var2;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
var str = "lasdjfl askjdfl askjdf kljlajpattern1lakjsdflajsdlfkj";
var match = str.match(/(.{10})pattern1(.{10})/i);
var text1 = match[1];
var text2 = match[2];
alert(text1);
alert(text2);
```

Results:

```
text1 = jdf kljlaj

text2 = lakjsdflaj
```

Comment: thanks, I think this is the Javascript, I need the PHP so I will use only the pattern, thanks anyway!